# Custom spinner doesn't update value

Tags: java, android, checkbox, spinner, adapter

I have an android spinner with a custom layout and a custom adapter.

When I tap on the spinner it shows a list of CheckButtons. I've associated a CheckboxListener to every checkbox so that when the checkbox is selected I want to change the value displayed by the Spinner.

In the CheckboxListener i take a reference to the spinner's TextView (the text displayed by the spinner). When i use the method `setText()` in the adapter the value displayed change but when i use that method in the CheckBoxListener the set text isn't displayed. I don't get why.

Here is part of the code:

**onCreate:**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter_apply);

        //get spinner reference
        Spinner spinnerLane = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.filt_apply_spinner_lane);

        //create adapter
        SpinnerAdapter adapterLane = new SpinnerAdapter(FilterApplyActivity.this,R.layout.spinner_row_layout,R.array.lanes_array,"Lane");

        //assegna gli adapter
        spinnerLane.setAdapter(adapterLane);

    }
```

**Custom adapter:**

```
class SpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    String[] data;
    CheckBoxListener chkboxListener;
    TextView displayedText;

    //Constructor
    {.....}

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_layout, parent, false);
        TextView row = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner_row_txt);
        displayedText = row;
        displayedText.setText("This is a text");
        row.setTypeface(custom_font);
        return layout;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.spinner_row_layout_check, parent, false);
        CheckBox row = (CheckBox) layout.findViewById(R.id.spinner_row_chk);
        row.setTag(position);
        chkboxListener = new CheckBoxListener(displayedText);
        row.setOnCheckedChangeListener(chkboxListener);     
        row.setText(data[position]);
        row.setTypeface(custom_font);
        return layout;
    }
}
```

**Custom listener:**

```
public class CheckBoxListener implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{
    String text;
    TextView txtView;

    public CheckBoxListener(TextView txt){
        txtView = txt;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
        text = "";
        System.out.println("row gettext 2: " + txtView.getText()); //when i tap on a chkbox it prints: "This is a text"
        if(isChecked == true){
            text = "bar";
            txtView.setText(text);
            System.out.println("txt gettext: " + txtView.getText()); //it prints: "bar"
            //txtView.invalidate();
        }
    }
}
```

**spinner_row_layout.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/very_dark_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/spinner_row_txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:text="foo"
        android:textColor="@color/orange_words" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**spinner_row_layout_check.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/very_dark_gray"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/spinner_row_chk"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="1dp"
        android:textColor="@color/orange_words"
        android:textSize="13dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### EDIT

[image: Spinner]

I need that when i check on the "Moderate" item like in the picture the displayed text "This is a text" changes with an arbitrary text.

Comment: Whenever you change the list in an adapter you should call .notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

To implement this in your code:

First, change the constructor of your CheckBoxListener and include your adapter as parameter.

Then, get the list of the adapter and change the item you want to change.

Last, call the .notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.

Comment: Maybe i wasn't clear in my question. I don't want to change the data with wich the adapter populates the view. I want that when i check the checkbox in the dropdown menu change the value of the spinner. I'll edit my question with an image to be more clear.